# Should procedures and/or functions of the DBMS_STANDARD package be used in PL/SQL code?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Recently, I encountered a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger on a table. In this trigger, the author relies on the `INSERTING` and `UPDATING` functions (both return a `BOOLEAN`) of the `DBMS_STANDARD` package to determine if the trigger was fired before an insert or before an update.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CUSTOMER_TRIGGER
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON CUSTOMER
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    /* Some code */
  END IF;

  IF UPDATING THEN
    /* Some other code */
  END IF;
END;
```

**Yes, I know that two, individual triggers could have been written to handle the two events separately. That's not the point of this question.**

After troubleshooting an error being received by these functions, we received word (from Oracle Support) that "dbms_standard routines are not really meant to be called by user programs". Is this true?

I find this a little strange, considering other procedures (such as `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` and `COMMIT`) are commonly used in PL/SQL code.

Comment: Do you have a metalink note or something else the public (or at least the Oracle-licensed public) can view?  And if not using the INSERTING / UPDATING calls to STANDARD in triggers, exactly when would they be used?

Comment: @Adam: No, this advise didn't come from a Metalink note. Rather, it came directly from Oracle Support on a Service Request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The functions INSERTING, UPDATING and DELETING are expressly provided for use in writing trigger code (see [trigger documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#i1025109)), so there is absolutely no proscription against using those.  Similarly, RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR is [documented](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i3329) to be intended for use by developers.

Having just DESCribed DBMS_STANDARD there are certainly some functions in there I don't know about and that perhaps shouldn't be used in your own code (for all I know) such as GRANTEE.

Generally, if you can find Oracle official documentation telling you how to use something, then it is OK to use it.

Comment: Excellent points! We will be talking with Oracle for clarification.

Comment: I suspect a level 1 analyst said "aha, DBMS_STANDARD isn't documented, and my handy dandy notebook tells customers not to use undocumented parameters or features without our guidance."